# How to call the following function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery.fn.daterangepicker = function(settings){
    var rangeInput = jQuery(this);

    //defaults
    var options = jQuery.extend({

    ........

    //function to format a date string        
    function fDate(date){
       if(!date.getDate()){return '';}
       var day = date.getDate();
```

It is being used as follow syntax

```
$('input').daterangepicker( {
                dateFormat : "M d, yy",
```

May I know how I can call function fDate?

I try

```
$('input').fDate(....)
```

but it doesn't work.

I get

$("input").fDate is not a function

The first portion of the code are from date picking library http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the code, you cannot call it from outside the local scope. To expose it (i.e. to be callable as `$('input').fDate ()`, you need to attach it to `jQuery.fn`.